# Is it possible to add a datalayer variable to all events at once?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, looker-studio, google-datalayer

In google tag manager, is there any way to insert variables in the datalayer for all datalayer events? For example have a 'userType' variable that is present in all events.

Do I have to manually add it to all my gtm events in dataLayer.push() or is there a handy work-around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You don't need to do it, the dataLayer is designed by default to persist variables across events** (except for the ecommerce dataLayer so there are no duplicate transactions):
https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/remember-to-flush-unused-data-layer-variables/

So if you push an event with a `foo` variable, that `foo` variable will also be available during later events.

**If you want a variable not to persist**, set it to undefined:

```
dataLayer.push({
  'event' : 'my_event',
  'foo' : undefined
});
```